# Mouse click event in jqplot does not draw data points in the graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using a mouse click event in jqplot to draw data points in a graph. However, clicking with the mouse does not draw the lines as expected. In the browser’s console I get the error “CurrentGraph.Plot.series[1] is undefined”. I cannot find the way to fix it. Thank you in advance, I will very much appreciate your help.

```
function SeriesClass(S,T)
{
this.SeriesNumber;
this.TimeSeries = S;
this.TitleSeries = T;
this.NewPeriods = [];
}

var SeriesList = [];    

// OBJECT CLASS DEFINTION FOR CURRENT GRAPH
function GraphClass()
{
this.Series = 0;    
this.Plot;          
this.Period = 56;   
}

var CurrentGraph = new GraphClass();

.........................

// FORECASTING OF DATA POINTS
function Start1()
{
$("#chart").show();
$("#GRAPH").dialog(
{
    title: "Data Point Set",
    height:800, width:1430,
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    show: "none", 
    hide: "none",       
    open: function() {DrawGraph();},
    buttons: 
    [
        {text: "reset points", id: "btn-reset", click: function()
            {
                var Data = SeriesList[CurrentGraph.Series];
                Data.NewPeriods.pop();
                if(CurrentGraph.Period==57)
                Data.NewPeriods.pop();
                DrawGraph();
                SetPeriod(56);
                $(".ui-button").hide();
                alert("Points Reset");
            }
        },
        {text: "next graph", id: "btn-next", click: function()
            {
                if(++CurrentGraph.Series===SeriesList.length)
                {

                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                    Completion();
                                        }
                else
                {
                    SetPeriod(56);
                    $(".ui-button").hide();
                    $("#chart").html('');
                    DrawGraph();
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

$(".ui-button").hide();
SetPeriod(56);

// mouse click event
$('#chart').bind('jqplotClick', function(event, seriesIndex, pointIndex,     data) 
{
    if(CurrentGraph.Period>0)
    {
        var X = Math.round(pointIndex.xaxis);
        var Y = Math.round(pointIndex.yaxis);
        if(X == CurrentGraph.Period)
        {
            var Data = SeriesList[CurrentGraph.Series];
            Data.NewPeriods.push(Y);

            CurrentGraph.Plot.series[1].data.push([X,Y]);
            CurrentGraph.Plot.drawSeries({},1);

            $("#btn-reset").show();

            if(CurrentGraph.Period==56)
            {
                SetPeriod(57); 
            }
            else if(CurrentGraph.Period==57)
            {
                SetPeriod(58); 
            }
            else
            {
                var Y1 = Data.NewPeriods[0];
                var Y2 = Data.NewPeriods[1];
                var Series = Data.SeriesNumber;
                $.getJSON("saveToFile.php", {S:Series, X1:56,Y1:Y1, X2:57,Y2:Y2});
                SetPeriod(0);
                $(".ui-button").show(); 
            }
        }
        else
            alert("Please click a value for period "+CurrentGraph.Period);
    }

});
}

........................

function DrawGraph()
{
$("#GraphNum").html("Company: "+(CurrentGraph.Title)+ " " + (CurrentGraph.Series+1)+" of "+SeriesList.length);

var Data = SeriesList[CurrentGraph.Series];
CurrentGraph.Plot = $.jqplot("chart", [Data.TimeSeries],
{
    stackSeries: false,
    series: false,


    axesDefaults: {tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,tickOptions: {angle:00, fontSize:'10pt'}},
    axes: 
    {
        xaxis: {tickInterval: 1, min:0, max:61, label:'DAYS'}, 
        yaxis: {tickInterval: 10, min: 0, max: 200, labelOptions:{angle: 45}, label:'PRICE'}
    },
    cursor: {show: true,followMouse: true},
});
}
```

Comment: do you have several series? shouldn't it be `CurrentGraph.Plot.series[0]` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question and leave your code in a minimal and precise version.

Comment: Dear Basile. Yes, I do have several series and changing CurrentGraph.Plot.series[1] to [0] does not change anything.

Comment: GalAbra, Thanks for your advice. I have edited the code and deleted unnecessary information.